# Ошибка входа. Проблемы с сертификатом

Tags: python, requests

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='lavafrai.ml', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/login (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)')))
```

Патаюсь залогинеться, но какие-то проблемы с сертификатом. Вместо https пробовал писать http но не помогало.

Мой код:

```
import requests
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

header = {'user-agent': UserAgent().random}
link = "https://lavafrai.ml/api/login"

data = {
    'email': "",
    'password': ""
}

responce = requests.post(link, data=data, headers=header)

print(responce)
```

Comment: Ну а вообще https://lavafrai.ml/ в браузере открывается?

Comment: Да, конечно открывается

Comment: `responce = requests.post(link, data=data, headers=header, verify=False)`

Answer (score -1):

Worked for me:

Add  verify=False

responce = requests.post(link, data=data, headers=header, **verify=False**)

Comment: Отключение проверки сертификата - плохая идея. Тупо открываете уязвимость к атаке Man-in-the-middle.

Comment: переведите, пожалуйста, текст ответа (нажав [edit] ниже текста ответа) на русский язык